# How to build Different Android Apps using ant scripts

Tags: android, ant

Hello i'm building a custom application.
PRE:

- The app will be restricted to a limited amount of user. ( let's say 20 people )
- The app should be unique per each user so each apk will refer to a user only.
- Each app should have a different package name

So i was starting to think a building script that takes the user list and creates 20 apks ( one for each user ) and updates the strings.xml file with the custom modification needed per-user.

But i really don't know where to start. Is there a good way or a tutorial where i can refer to ?

Just to be clear i'd like to have a manifest like this:

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="$pname"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
        <application>...</application>
    </manifest>
```

And then replace the $pname using ant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for the aapt command. It has an additional flag --rename-manifest-package. The help says

> ```
>  Rewrite the manifest so that its package name is the package name
>  given here.  Relative class names (for example .Foo) will be
>  changed to absolute names with the old package so that the code
>  does not need to change.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I would be using 20 different semi-empty default activities (one per each of users) located in 20 different packages extending 1 real activity, like:

```
mypackage.user01.MyMainActivity extends mypackage.MyMainActivity;
mypackage.user02.MyMainActivity extends mypackage.MyMainActivity;
mypackage.user03.MyMainActivity extends mypackage.MyMainActivity;
...
mypackage.user20.MyMainActivity extends mypackage.MyMainActivity;
```

And then 20 different androidmanifests.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="mypackage.userXX">
    <application
            android:icon="@drawable/MyIcon"
            android:label="@string/MyApplication"
           >
        <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/MyActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name="mypackage.MyActivity"
                android:label="@string/MyActivity"/>
        <activity
                android:name="mypackage.user01.MyActivity"
                android:label="@string/MyActivity"/>
        <!-- etc. till user20 -->
    </application>
</manifest>
```

which will be copied using simple Ant copy tasks to real one - it's easy to implement, though a bit boring :)

Comment: Thanks @barmaley, ways to replace the mypackage.userXX inside the <manifest> tag with something like $pname and using ant with a command line like:
ant release -Dpname=mypackage.user00 ?

Comment: Never tried... Actually the same approach (as described in my post) I'm using in my application - to divide between lite and full version. For sure it would be nice to automate replacing application package inside of manifest, but I don't know how to do it. I'm not really expert in Anting...

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler if you store 20 codes in your app, and give one code to each customer. Then just give each customer the same application. The application changes its properties depending on what code was entered.

If this sounds like the right approach, I'll see if I can code some specific aspects. If it isn't the approach you're after, please could you give me a bit more information on how these 20 people would be identified?

Comment: Yes, that would be a nice idea if i could do that way. I can't explain why but i do need to build 20 different apks with 20 different package names and some different string values.

Comment: The thing is, using a Hex-Editor a string can easily be manipulated.

Comment: What do you mean by package names? In other words, where would the user be seeing this "package name", if anywhere?

Comment: Andrea, how worried are you about the security? How likely is it that someone would try to hack it?

Comment: There are a lot of questions, and a lot of ways of doing things. It would be useful if you could give more information to your post, explaining the nature of the app and these people

Comment: @jodes :) lol i'm not worried. The guy who asked that is worried about that. I already tried with other super secure (but easier) solution but he want the app developed that way.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use some unique device-identifier. There was an intersting article about that on the [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html).

If you want to create a build-script, you can use [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I was thinking to use Ant. But i really have no clue on how to achieve the package name task. ( because i'm probably a noob on using ant )

Comment: I don't think changing the package name is a good pratice to archive this. See if you can use the Device-ID.

Comment: I already tried, but the client doesn't want to hear nothing on this topic. He wants that way.